# Matlab: multidimensional correlation coefficients

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, correlation, cross-correlation

Lets say that I have 10 datasets, 30 elements each. We can simulate it as:

```
A = rand(30, 10);
```

so each dataset is in one column. Now, I want to find set of `n` datasets which are correlated (or uncorrelated, whatever...).

For `n=2` I can simply use `R = corr(A)` and find out that i.e. columns 1 and 3 show the highest correlation between each other.  But what if I want to find set of three, or four correlated (or uncorrelated) datasets between each other? Is there a function for that or do I have to loop it somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: What would your loop like?  In other words, how would you define the correlation between three vectors?  I'm not saying that you couldn't find meaningful results, but I'm not sure if there is a standard definition for the correlation of three vectors simultaneously.

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea about the loop. It was just sort of random thought... Maybe I should just base on 2D correlation and use correlation coefficients to select datasets... Anyway, thanks for any ideas on that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can treat this as a random simulation problem. You pick three (four) datasets and find the largest cross-correlation score, which I define as sum of pairwise correlation score.

```
max_score = 0;
max_set = [];
max_prev = 0;
counter = 0;
while 1,
    idx = randperm(10);
    idx = idx(1:3); % or 1:4 for case of four
    score = R(idx(1), idx(2)) + R(idx(2), idx(3)) + R(idx(1), idx(3));
    if score > max_score,
        max_score = score;
        max_set = idx;
    end
    counter = counter + 1;
    if mod(counter, 1000) == 0, % every 1000 iteration check convergence
        if max_score - max_prev < 0.0001,
            break;
        end
    end
    max_prev = max_score;
end
```

Althought it is not a deterministic process, it doesn't take long to converge and give you global optimal.

Comment: That is perfect for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Art You can check my updated code, which includes convergence loop-breaking. Should be more handy!

Comment: I agree that the sum of pairwise correlations is probably the best choice.  However, it might be a bit of a stretch to call this "convergence."  You are taking random samples and expecting that eventually you will stop finding better answers. The algorithm is not guaranteed to perform any better than a brute-force search, and has the possibility of performing worse.

Comment: @nispio I totally agree with your point and a brute force search should be better.

Comment: Your algorithm is essentially a Monte Carlo method, and I think with some modifications, it could beat brute force.  For example, consider the following update step:  Randomly replace one (not all) of the three indices and re-evaluate the objective function.  If it has improved, keep the update.  If it has not improved, keep it with some probability `p`.  (Typically `p` is chosen to be proportional to the change in the objective function.)

Comment: For the record, the brute-force approach to this problem will give an exact solution in 120 iterations for 3 vectors, and in 210 iterations for 4, so that's the benchmark to beat. :)

Answer (score 2):

As a really simple starting point you could take the sum down the columns of R to find the column that is the most correlated with the others.  Then, from that column choose two columns that are the most strongly correlated with it.  Something like this:

```
[~, ii] = max(sum(R));
[~, jj] = sort(R(:,ii),'descend');
three_cols = jj(1:3);
```

Alternatively you could locate the highest correlation value in the matrix, and then search along its column and row to find the next highest value, etc.